# Java heap space error while parsing large xml file

Tags: java, xml

I want to parse a large xml file(785mb) and write the data to csv. I am getting java heapspace error(out of memory) when I try to parse the file.
I tried increasing the heap size to 1024mb but the code could handle a file of 50mb maximum.

Please let me know a solution for parsing large xml file in java.

Comment: One thing that I've learned when parsing data from a file is not to cache it. Ensure that you're not pulling the entire file into an object.

Comment: Do you use a SAX or DOM parser?

Comment: If you use 32-bit java you won't go over cca 1.5GB of heap space

Comment: I am working on a 32 bit machine and using DOM parser.

Comment: Use a SAX parser. It takes stream approach to loading and parsing of the xml file. Whichever parser you are using seem to be loading the entire xml file into memory and that could be/likely causing the issue. Google for SAX parsers, you will find one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a SAXParser instead of a DOMParser
The difference is that it doesn't load the complete XML data in memory.

Look at this tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Regards,

Romain.

Comment: I cannot use a SAX parser as the tags in the xml file are unknown. So I won't be able to create a error handler for SAX parser.

Comment: Ok so the StAX parser might be a better choice for you because it uses an iterator approach.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to use Streaming Api for XML (StAX).
Here is good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html#javastax).